# Flutter with UI Avatar returning invalid image

Tags: laravel, flutter

I am working on pulling my user profiles into my flutter app, but for some reason I am getting image invalid when using Image.Network when the user's profile photo is coming from ui-avatars.com, it works fine when it is just returning a jpg.

```
FutureBuilder<User>(
              future: futureUser,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Image.network(
                    snapshot.data!.profilePhotoUrl,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    width: 90,
                    height: 90,
                  );
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('${snapshot.error}');
                }
                // By default, show a loading spinner.
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              },
            ),
```

For reference here is the URL that is being returned in the users profile from ui-avatars: https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=m&color=7F9CF5&background=EBF4FF

Error in console:

```
Exception caught by image resource service 
The following _Exception was thrown resolving an image codec:
Exception: Invalid image data

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _futurize (dart:ui/painting.dart:5886:5)
#1      ImageDescriptor.encoded (dart:ui/painting.dart:5741:12)
#2      instantiateImageCodecFromBuffer (dart:ui/painting.dart:2092:60)
#3      PaintingBinding.instantiateImageCodecFromBuffer (package:flutter/src/painting/binding.dart:153:15)
#4      NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:135:22)
<asynchronous suspension>
Image provider: NetworkImage("https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=m&color=7F9CF5&background=EBF4FF", scale: 1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=m&color=7F9CF5&background=EBF4FF", scale: 1.0)
```

Test Screen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Test',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Test'),
        ),
        body: Image.network(
          'https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=m&color=7F9CF5&background=EBF4FF',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          width: 90,
          height: 90,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am fairly new to Flutter.

Comment: Do you get data on `snapshot.data!.profilePhotoUrl,`? like printing inside `if (snapshot.hasData) { ..here` or on debug mode?

Comment: Hi I am getting the data returned in the snapshot, I will add the error in the main question

Comment: Can you include your test device name? Also try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app

Comment: Hi Yeasin, I have run flutter clean and rebuilt and I am still getting the issue. The test device is Pixel 4 API 30.

Comment: Can you try on running web

Comment: Hi Yeasin, it doesnt work in web either. Same issue

Comment: I've tested with the dummy future as String with this URL, working fine, Can you include full sample widget , also I am using flutter 3.3.3, you can try upgrading

Comment: I am currently using flutter 3.3.4 and I have added the full test screen I am using above.

Comment: working fine here. try to upgrade again `flutter upgrade -f`

Comment: No luck, I have zero clue why it wont work for me

Answer (score 1):

The issue is missing size parameter and you can fix is easily by adding size at the end of url. Define variable or just add fixed number at the end.

```
String image_size = "150";
return Image.network("https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=m&color=7F9CF5&background=EBF4FF&size=$image_size");
```